# What happens to lines of Java .properties file which don't match the key value pattern

Tags: java, xml, properties

I have a java library which I need to treat as a black box and which requires a properties file to exist on the class path. However, I have a system in place which only allows the serving of configuration files which contain valid xml.

Due to the black box nature of the jar I am unable to recompile using the `loadFromXml()` method, or ask the owner so to do.

To solve this apparent mismatch I have been able to provide a config file which look like this:

```
<dummy>
key1=value1
key2=value2
</dummy>
```

This works fine and provides the values that I want access to.

I can not find a reference to what happens to the first and last line of this malformed properties file.

Does anybody know what happens? Do they have a better solution?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the problem with your xml-file?

Comment: Your config file looks somewhat like the INI file format.  What happens if you don't include the </dummy> line?  Your solution is as good as any as long as it works for your process.

Comment: Essentially it feels like the kind of thing which could be easily misunderstood if I ever move on from the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You end up with an empty string value for the keys `"<dummy>"` and `"</dummy>"`. You can show this easily:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("test.properties")) {
            properties.load(input);
        }

        for (String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
            System.out.println(key + " = '" + properties.get(key) + "'");
        }
    }
}
```

This is at least somewhat indicated in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) with this part:

> As a third example, the line:
>
> ```
> cheeses
> ```
>
> specifies that the key is "cheeses" and the associated element is the empty string "".

... but it's not as clearly written as it might be.